# How to call ICaptureGraphBuilder2->RenderStream twice?

Tags: directshow

I have read in msdn [RenderStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that we can call `RenderStream` multiple time to make long filter chain. I have following filter chain:

```
Capture Filter -> Sample Grabber -> Transformation Filter -> Video Mixing Renderer9
```

I'm trying to do the same using `RenderStream` programmatically.

```
pBuid->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,&MEDIATYPE_Video,pCap,pSampleGrabber,pTransformFilter);

pBuid->RenderStream(NULL,NULL,pTransformFilter,NULL,pVMRender);
```

But, above code does not work. After executing, first `RenderStream` it shows console window(win32) and does nothing. 
Please help me how can I render `Capture->Sample Grabber->Transform Filter->Renderer`.

Comment: No, it goes to console window immediately after executing first render stream statement and cursor keeps blinking @ console window. I have checked the same filter chain with "grapgedt" and works fine....renders web cam preview.

Comment: Have you tried registering the FilterGraph in the ROT (Running object table) and then to look with GraphEdit or GraphStudioNext which filters you get after your first call? Maybe you have a problem with the Mediatypes.
Have you added the filters to the graph before the RenderStream call? (common mistake: not only create the filters but also add to the graph)

Comment: In GraphStudioNext you can also try to add all needed filters and not connect them! Then execute "Render Pin" and watch what happens.

Comment: It cannot just go to console. Run under debugger with "break on exception" enabled and you will see some error taking place.

Comment: I have not checked on the ROT, but wit only GraphEdt. Yes, I have added all filters using pGraph->AddFilter() before RenderStream. I have never used ROT. so not much idea about it. As you suspect, the problem could be of media type then why it works in GraphEdt ?

Comment: Oh, I debugged more and found that if I don't add my transform filter into chain and call RenderStream twice then it works & renders video. But when I add my transform filter it creates some problem. pBuid->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,&MEDIATYPE_Video,pCap,NULL,pSampleGrabber);

pBuid->RenderStream(NULL,NULL,pSampleGrabber,NULL,pVMRender); this works if I don't add my transform filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Pin_Category_preview` if you are using `videoRenderer`. Try the following:

```
pBuid->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,&MEDIATYPE_Video,pCap,pSampleGrabber,pTransformFilter);

pBuid->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW,&MEDIATYPE_Video,pCap,null,null); //the preview pin automatically connects to the renderer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue:
@CPlusSharp, 
you were right it was media type issue. I set proper media tyep for AM_MEDIATYPE.
Thanks to all for help :)

Comment: what tools helped you find the problem?